# How can I get a list of ships I own and their location?

Tags: eve-online

As I'm getting older it's getting harder to remember where I parked all my ships. I tend to leave some in systems that are likely to see action in the near future, to be able to quickly reship if the need arises.

But I'm losing track of the locations of my ships, I'd like to have a nice overview of the locations of all my ships. I would have expected the assets window to be able to do that, but I couldn't find our how to show me only my ships.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there's no easy in game method for determining the location of all of your ships, don't forget that the asset window does have a search feature.  For instance, if you're looking for your prized Ferox, you can search for Ferox in the asset window and it will give you the location of any Feroxes (Feroxen?) that you may own.

Additionally, when looking at assets for a particular station, you can sort the assets by volume.  Generally speaking, this will put all of your ships at the top (or bottom) of the asset list as you're not likely to own much that's bigger than a ship.

Lastly, I've not used it myself, but according to one of my alliance mates, EveHQ may be able to provide exactly what you're looking for.  Apparently the asset manager in the program is very full featured.  http://www.evehq.net/

Comment: You can also filter the Map by locations where you have stuff laying around, iirc. Did not play for a while.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Android device you can get [Aura](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aideronrobotics.android.aura&hl=en) for Android. One of the many things that allows you to do is view your assets, and even has a tab for all of your ships and their locations.

Full disclosure: The CEO of my corp is the developer of Aura, but I found him in game because I liked his product, and I am a fellow Android developer.

Answer (score 1):

Alt+T should open your [Personal Assets] window, (or you can click the "safe containing a star" icon on the left, below halfway down.) That will give you a list of all the stuff you have left, all over the universe.

You can search for "ship" to see where you left all or any ships.

Answer (score 0):

To find your ships (and all your other assets) across all you accounts and characters I can recommend using the 3rd party tool: [jEveAssets](https://eve.nikr.net/jeveasset).